# Sum then average values in a string of strings using Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

If I am given an json.dumps( output that gives a response as the following when focusing on a particular aspect of the response:

```
[["player1-game1", 2,2,4,5],["player1-game2",6,8,8,9]]
```

I would like to have it output the average of player one given 2 or infinite number of games played.

What code must I use to get the average of those values in that string:

I would like it to print out the average of elements in [1], [2],... but not in [0] since it's a string.

How might I do this using Python 2.7; I tried using a combination of for loops even trying to set some value to an array in case I had thousands of players or stats.

The output I am hoping to get is:

```
[player-1, 4,5,6,7]
```

So [1,...] is the average of ["player-1",(2+6)/2,(8+2)/2,(4+8)/2,(9+5)/2]

Sorry I should have clarified.

Comment: Just because it's awesome, in Python 3 (Definitely 3.5 and I think earlier), you can use unpacking to do the split for you; if `orig` is that original list: `[(k, sum(scores)/len(scores)) for k, *scores in orig]`. Unpacking generalizations are awesome. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to slice each list so that the first element is always treated separately and the rest of the elements as another list. Once you do that, you can easily extract it's average. E.g., using list comprehension:

```
orig =  [["player1-game1", 2,2,4,5], ["player1-game2",6,8,8,9]]
result = [ [x[0], float(sum(x[1:]))/len(x[1:])] for x in orig]
```

Comment: Why not `result = [ [x[0], float(sum(x[1:]))/len(x[1:])] for x in orig]`?

Comment: @Sait good point, fixed. Old (read: bad) habits die hard, I guess.

Comment: So I can print the sum/average of these individual stats by using print json.dumps(array[n][24]), but I don't want to have 16 different variables that I've set to zero then 16 different lines that print a slightly different stat that's in a different element of the array. I just want to make it so I could print infinitely number of stats/averages for infinitely number of games.

Comment: By the way, there is a typo: `oring`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comp with an inner gex exp so you only slice each sublist once, you can pass `0.0` as the start value to `sum` so you can avoid needing to cast to float for the division.

```
l = [["player1-game1", 2,2,4,5],["player1-game2",6,8,8,9]]

res = [[_nm, sum(_sub, 0.0) / len(_sub)] for _nm, _sub in ((sub[0],sub[1:]) for sub in l)]
```

Output:

```
[['player1-game1', 3.25], ['player1-game2', 7.75]]
```

If you are actually trying to get the average of pairwise elements from each sublist you can transpose the elements:

```
from itertools import izip
l = [["player1-game1", 2,2,4, 5],["player1-game2",6,8,8,9]]
zipped = izip(*l)
player = next(zipped)
print([(a+b( / 2.0 for a,b in zipped])
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

If you want to add the player to the list:

```
 [player[0]]+[(a+b) / 2.0 for a,b in zipped]
```

You may find a *dictionary* to be a much more convenient structure to use for your data.

Comment: [["player-1-game1", "date", "win/loss","y","n",1,2,3,4],["player-1-game2", "date", "win/loss","y","n",1,2,3,4]] would I do the following: result = [ [x[0:5], float(sum(x[6:]))/len(x[6:])] for x in orig] I'm trying to print an average of first element in the first list and the second list. Eg: If that were the case I would get [player-1, 4,5,,6,7]